# securityContext auto generated for pod when securityContext is added for container

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have a pod with two containers out of which one container has a default security context with runAsNonRoot set to true. On deploying it in kubernetes, the generated yaml file has applies securityContext to the pod as well with runAsGroup and runAsUser set to 1000. I am not able to understand how the runAsGroup and runAsUser values are set for the whole pod and not for the container alone

Comment: Any chance you can post your deployment YAML?